# What are the steps to upgrade from Db2 10.5 to DB2 11.1 with loosing any persisted data

Tags: db2

We are currently using 10.5 version of DB2 and we are planning to upgrade to 11.1 version of DB2. I would like to know if the upgrade scenario does backup of the persisted data of 10.5 DB2 version to a specific location and after the upgrade the Db2 picks same data from the backup location?

If there is no provision in such a way of a backup location, would like to know the steps to backup the persisted data and other things I have to take into consideration while making the upgrade.

Comment: Take a look at [Upgrade to Db2 Version 11.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.upgrade.doc/doc/c0023662.html)

Answer (score 0):

During a Db2 upgrade, it is *your* responsibility to take a backup copy of the database prior to the the upgrade.

There are instructions here within the overall *Database Fundamentals - Upgrating* section of the manuals

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.upgrade.doc/doc/t0007139.html